# FTDI D2XX API in C works on command-line console but always returns zero in application which is built by Xcode and Swift programming on macOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift5, ftdi

I'm trying to build an macOS application on masOS to communicate with FTDI D2XX device.
I used gcc to compile a simple console app with C code and it works well and get expected device count.
But when I tried to import the FTDI into Xcode and built an application with Swift 5. The application can be built and executed successfully but it always return 0 for FTDI device count.
I tried to use two methods to import FTDI D2XX static library (ftd2xx.a) into Xcode. But both of them have same results.

1. Created C wrapper and bridging header for calling FTDI D2XX API
2. Created module and use “import xxx”

The C code to call FTDI D2XX API is:

```
int queryDeviceCount(void)
{
     FT_STATUS         ftStatus;
     DWORD             numDevs = 999;

     ftStatus = FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(&numDevs);
     if (ftStatus == FT_OK) {
           return numDevs;
     }

     return 0;
}
```

When FT_CreateDeviceInfoList is called, it returned FT_OK in ftStatus. But the numDevs is always zero (it should get 2 in my setup).
I think the FTDI D2XX driver should be OK in my MacBookPro because it works well in command-line console.
So, I'm wondering is there any difference in calling FTDI API between command-line console and GUI application. I'm pretty sure that the FTDI API is called correctly in GUI application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in macOS GUI App, the system resource is protected. I need to enable the USB access ability in "App Sandbox" to use USB access APIs.
App Sandbox appears in the Signing & Capabilities pane of Xcode revealing additional controls to configure the capability.
[image: USB access in App Sandbox]